# Eclipse RCP widgets don't resize based on the systems font size

Tags: windows, fonts, widget, eclipse-rcp, grid-layout

Using GridLayout and GridData, everything is sized correctly in my Eclipse RCP application. The problem occurs when I change the default Windows font to a larger size than the normal. In that case, RCP will not take into account also the font size (it renders everything as if the font was normal sized). Hadn't find any working solution so far.

Example code:

```
    @Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    GridData gridData;
    Composite newContainer;

    newContainer = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true);
    newContainer.setLayoutData(gridData);

    mainLayout = new GridLayout(2, true);
    mainLayout.marginHeight = 5;
    mainLayout.marginWidth = 5;
    mainLayout.marginLeft = 5;
    mainLayout.marginRight = 5;
    mainLayout.horizontalSpacing = 15;
    mainLayout.verticalSpacing = 10;
    newContainer.setLayout(mainLayout);

    taskNameLabel = new Label(newContainer, SWT.LEFT);
    taskNameLabel.setText(Messages.LABEL_TASK_NAME);
    gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, 0, true, true, 1, 1);
    taskNameLabel.setLayoutData(gridData);
    taskNameText = new Text(newContainer, SWT.LEFT | SWT.BORDER);
    gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, 0, true, true, 1, 1);
    taskNameText.setLayoutData(gridData);

    commentsLabel = new Label(newContainer, SWT.LEFT);
    commentsLabel.setText(Messages.LABEL_COMMENTS);
    gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, 0, true, true, 1, 1);
    commentsLabel.setLayoutData(gridData);
    commentsText = new Text(newContainer, SWT.LEFT | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.MULTI | SWT.WRAP);
    gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, 0, true, true, 1, 1);
    gridData.heightHint = 100;
    commentsText.setLayoutData(gridData);
    SwtTextUtil.allowTabOnMultiText(commentsText);

    durationLabel = new Label(newContainer, SWT.LEFT);
    durationLabel.setText(Messages.LABEL_DURATION);
    gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, 0, true, true, 1, 1);
    durationLabel.setLayoutData(gridData);
    durationSpinner = new Spinner(newContainer, SWT.LEFT | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP);
    durationSpinner.setDigits(1);
    durationSpinner.setMinimum(1);
    durationSpinner.setMaximum(PipetteConstants.MAX_BEEPER_DURATION_DS);
    durationSpinner.setSelection(1);
    durationSpinner.setIncrement(1);
    gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, 0, true, true, 1, 1);
    durationSpinner.setLayoutData(gridData);
    SpinnerUtil.get().addSpinnerValidation(durationSpinner, PipetteConstants.MAX_BEEPER_DURATION_S, 0.1);

    displayTextLabel = new Label(newContainer, SWT.LEFT);
    displayTextLabel.setText(Messages.LABEL_DISPLAY_TEXT);
    gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, 0, true, true, 1, 1);
    displayTextLabel.setLayoutData(gridData);
    displayTextText = new Text(newContainer, SWT.LEFT | SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI);
    gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, 0, true, true, 1, 1);
    gridData.heightHint = 50;
    displayTextText.setLayoutData(gridData);
    SwtTextUtil.allowTabOnMultiText(displayTextText);

    requiredLabel = new Label(parent, SWT.LEFT);
    requiredLabel.setText(Messages.LABEL_REQUIRED);
    gridData = new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, 0, false, false, 2, 1);
    requiredLabel.setLayoutData(gridData);

    return newContainer;
}
```

Although font size is changed when I read the height of the font, it is the same as when using normal sized fonts - is this maybe a bug, where getHeight() method of a getFontData() method of the font object returns wrong information, which in turn RCP uses for its widget layout/positioning?

```
getShell().getDisplay().getSystemFont().getFontData()[0].getHeight()
```

and

```
newContainer.getFont().getFontData()[0].getHeight()
```

both return 9, no matter the size of the fonts on the windows, although the fonts do change their size.

Comment: Show us an example of your code

Comment: Try calling `applyDialogFont(newContainer)` just before the `return newContainer`